# Understanding featured based folder structure for React projects

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, architecture, directory-structure

I'm using a **featured based** React architecture [documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-structure.html#grouping-by-features-or-routes) and I get the general concept behind it, but I have some questions about it:

1. What If I need to use code of one feature in other feature? this can be allowed? according to featured separation concept each feature must be isolated with its own modules/code.
2. How can I enable communication between features?

One posible situation can be, `useAuth` hook, this going to handle authentication proccess in the app with things like `login`, `logout` and other methods, so its neccesary to this functionality can be accesible by any feature, then I could have two possible places which I can place this hook:

1. Create a folder called `hooks`, where global hooks going to live, and there put the `useAuth` hook.
2. Create a feature called `authentication` with a hook folder on it and put there our `useAuth` hook but, How can I make this hook visible to the other features?

Answer (score 0):

For your first question,

> What If I need to use code of one feature in other feature? this can be allowed? according to featured separation concept each feature must be isolated with its own modules/code.

You could just put the `useAuth` hook in the `common/` folder or maybe if you have too many, use your idea of another folder.

> How can I enable communication between features?

With the standard React Context API, you can create a file that makes a context, and import the context when needed. For more advanced state management you will need a library like MobX.